# function getAllInternetHeadersAsync return null value in localhost environment

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get internet header properties on an email (outlook addin).
I use the following code :

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(function(asyncResult) {
if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
  console.log("Internet headers received successfully");
  console.log(asyncResult.value);
}
});
```

The first log is displayed, meaning the result is succeeded. But the second log display empty value.
When I use the script lab addin in the same mailbox, then I successfuly get the internet headers.

Is it possible to execute these kind of function in a localhost environment or do I have to publish my addin ?
Thank you for your help
David

Comment: (1) There is no requirement to submit this add-in to store for this API to work. This API should work in your dev environment as well.
(2) Are you using "Outlook Web", "Outlook Desktop" (Windows) or "Outlook Mac" (MacOS) for testing your add-in?
(3) Is code executed in your add-in and ScriptLab add-in exactly same?
(4) Are you using requirement set 1.8 correctly? This API is supported in 1.8 set.

Comment: For more updates, follow up on Github- https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1992

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you specified the right requirement set in the manifest file of your add-in. The `getAllInternetHeadersAsync` method was introduced in the version 1.8.

The following code works like a charm from a locally hosted add-in:

```
var headers = "";
// Get the internet headers related to the mail.
Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(
     function(asyncResult) {
         if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
             headers = asyncResult.value;
             console.log(headers);

         } else {
            if (asyncResult.error.code == 9020) {
              // GenericResponseError returned when there is no context.
              // Treat as no context.
         } else {
              // Handle the error.
           }
       }
     }
  );
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I have double checked and the internet headers are successfuly retrieved when I stay on the same browser window (with chrome and o365). As soon as I open the email in a new window (dialog) my addin retrieves null internet headers, and script lab retrieve null value as well. Ils there some limitation on dialog window ?.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest filing an issues on the `OfficeJS` repo in GitHub.

Comment: will do it Thank you Eugene